# Не работает сервер на heroku, как исправить?

Tags: node.js, heroku

При get запросе возникает ошибка

> 2020-10-29T13:18:51.321673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
> host=frozen-sands-21043.herokuapp.com
> request_id=d28b58f9-be90-4bbb-87b9-b2d64eea5261 fwd="188.163.31.152"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

```
var http=require('http');
var port=process.env.PORT||'8080';
http.createServer().on('request', function(req, res){
  res.end('Hello');
}).listen(port,function(){
  console.log('Server Run');
});
```

Comment: выложите Procfile

Comment: `>heroku local
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
16:00:55 web.1   |  npm
16:00:55 web.1   |   ERR! missing script: start
16:00:55 web.1   |  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
16:00:55 web.1   |  npm ERR!     C:\Users\newai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-30T14_00_55_350Z-debug.log
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
16:00:55 web.1   Exited with exit code null`

Comment: ну дык, эт самое. `web: node index.js` или что-то более подходящее вашему проекту

Comment: или start в scripts package.json прописать. в логе же всё об этом сказано

Comment: Дык прописано 
{
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "script":{
   "start": "index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.x"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.3.x"
  }
}